# AnyEvent equivalent to Event var watcher?

Tags: perl, event-handling

I'm using an `Event` var watcher to implement an internal queue. When the producer thread adds something to the queue (just an array) it will change the value of a watched variable to signal that an element was added.

How can you do the same with `AnyEvent`? It doesn't seem to support variable watching. Do I have to use pipes and use an IO watcher (i.e. the producer writes a byte on one end of the pipe when it has added an element.)

I'd also be interested to know how to do this with `Coro`.

Comment: Seems you should make your queue a simple object, perhaps even an AnyEvent::Condvar subclass, which calls ->begin for each element added to the queue and an event which handles it and calls end on that same condvar

Comment: In Coro, you would use a Coro::Channel, have a listening side looping on $channel->get and the sending side sending with $channel->put

Comment: If you need to watch variables, look at tieing the variables or adding magic to the queue with Variable::Magic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the paradigm to use:

```
my @queue;
my $queue_watcher;

sub add_item {
   push(@queue, $_[0]);
   $queue_watcher ||= AnyEvent->timer(after => 0, cb => \&process_queue);
}

sub process_queue {
  ... # remove zero or more elements from @queue
  if (@queue) {
    $queue_watcher = AnyEvent->timer(after => 0, cb => \&process_queue);
  } else {
    undef $queue_watcher;
  }
}
```

Basically `$queue_watcher` is defined and active if and only if `@queue` is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you are using variable watching as means of transferring control back to the consumer. In AnyEvent, this can be done with condition variables by calling $cv->send() from the producer and $cv->recv() in the consumer. You could consider send()ing the item that you'd otherwise have put in the queue, but calling send without parameters should be an allowed way of notifying the consumer.

Comment: But from the `AnyEvent` documentation, "You can only wait once on a condition - additional calls are valid but will return immediately." My producer will produce a stream of items, not just a single item.

Comment: Then you are looking for $cv->begin and $cv->end methods which are paired which can take a custom callback set at begin which gets called at end (and you can create new condvars for this).

Comment: But I want to process the elements as they are produced.